# How do you delete a specific table in sqlite in android studio?

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, sql-delete

Ive got an app that im creating where i want to be able to type in the users username and click delete then it will delete all of the data for that specific user, Eg-address, phone, birthdate. But for some reason when on the manage user activity when i click the remove button which should take me to the remove activity it takes me back to the main activity instead! Can anyone see what ive done wrong please!!!

Remove class:

```
public class Remove extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelperUser myDb;

Button btRemove = findViewById(R.id.buttonRemove);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_remove);

    final EditText etUser = findViewById(R.id.editTextUser);
    myDb = new DatabaseHelperUser(this);


    btRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Integer deletedRows = myDb.deleteData(etUser.getText().toString());
            if(deletedRows > 0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data has not been Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

        }
    });


}
```

}

DatabaseHelperUser class:

```
public class DatabaseHelperUser extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "User.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "User_table";
public static final String COL1 = "UserNum";
public static final String COL2 = "UserName";
public static final String COL3 = "Password";
public static final String COL4 = "BirthDate";
public static final String COL5 = "Phone";
public static final String COL6 = "Address";


public  DatabaseHelperUser(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (UserNum TEXT,UserName Text,Password Text,BirthDate Text,Phone Text,Address Text)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
public Cursor getData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return res;
}
public Integer deleteData(String UserName){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "UserName = ?", new String[] {UserName});

}
```

}

Manage user class:

```
public class ManagingUsers extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_managing_users);

    final Button btadd = findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
    final Button btInventory = findViewById(R.id.buttonInventory2);
    final Button btView = findViewById(R.id.buttonView);
    final Button btRemove = findViewById(R.id.buttonRemove);

    btadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Add.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    btInventory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Inventory.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    btView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.example.assignment3.View.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    btRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.example.assignment3.Remove.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });



}
```

}

Comment: *...and click delete then it will delete all of the data for that specific user* Where is the code for the listener of the button that you click? Is there any button in the activity?

Comment: Sorry I explained it terribly ive updated my question if that makes better sense now?